# Issue with Row in Bottom App Bar that I'm not understanding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

so I'm trying to implement a somewhat custom bottom navigation bar. I am trying to center my icons and after further investigation it is indeed working "correctly" in a way but the issue is that the bottom half of the bottom app bar gets completely ignored.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/wGOPdxY.png]

[image]

No matter what I do, the bottom half gets ignored. If I increase the size, it only makes it bigger at the top which is not what I want. How can I get the row to respect the entire bottom app bar?

Here's my code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, bottom: 33.0, right: 30.0),
   child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      child: BottomAppBar(
         color: Color(0xFF222222),
         child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
               Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                     'assets/images/home.svg',
                  ),
                ),
               Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                     'assets/images/discover.svg',
                  ),
               ),
               Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                     'assets/images/heart.svg',
                  ),
               ),
               Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                     'assets/images/user.svg',
                  ),
               ),
            ],
         ),
      ),
   ),
),
```

Comment: You set padding on bottom to 30. This is the reason why it is getting ignored

Comment: the padding is just to make the bottom app bar come out from the bottom. The issue I'm referring to is still there even if I take out the padding

https://i.imgur.com/Fiv1svK.png
https://i.imgur.com/Sagpv1a.png

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to wrap BottomAppBar with SafeArea. Shoutout to Flutter discord for help on this :)

```
bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            child: BottomAppBar(
              color: Color(0xFF222222),
              child: Container(
                height: 88.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/images/home.svg',
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            left: 23.0,
                            bottom: 0,
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/Ellipse5.png'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/discover.svg',
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/heart.svg',
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/user.svg',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```